# Using stringByAppendingString to add character to existing string in Xcode/objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to add the character "1" to the existing value of a textbox "output" in Xcode objective-C.

I am trying to use the "stringByAppendingString" function, and have looked at some examples and can't seem to get this to work.

Is my syntax just wrong?

```
- (IBAction)pressOne:(id)sender {
    NSString *str1 = output.text;

    output.text = [str1  stringByAppendingString:[@"1"];

}
```

Comment: What's your problem? The code doesn't  compile? Do you have an error when running the app? Or is the text box not updated?

Comment: your problem is related to NSString class so read first documentation of NSString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the stray bracket before the `@` symbol:

```
output.text = [str1 stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

try `[str1  stringByAppendingString:@"1"];`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets:

```
output.text = [str1  stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
```